# Conductivity and free/bound charge for conductors, insulators/dielectrics and semiconductors

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electricity, electric-current, charge

I am slightly confused about the distinction between these three types of material in terms of

a) conductivity

b) the idea of free and bound charge

If we consider the distinction between these in terms of conductivity, then we have conductors having conductivity much greater thn 1 (infinite for ideal conductor), insulators having conductivity much less than 1, and it is intermediate for semiconductors (Elements of Electromagnetics, Sadiku)

But, if I am not mistaken, conductivity refers to the ability for charge to flow. The relation $J=\sigma E$ tells me that, no matter how small the conductivity, there will be some finite current for any material placed in an external magnetic field.

Yet considering the definitions microscopically, I was under the impression that insulators/dielectrics have (almost exclusively) bound charge. This would mean that there would come a point at which there is no flowing charge despite a non-zero electric field and conductivity.

The only resolution I can think of is that the equation $J=\sigma E$ refers exclusively to free charge, although I have not seen this stated anywhere.

I would greatly appreciate if someone could clarify these differences.